# If integration of arbitrary polynomial with respect to Borel measure $\mu$, over $[0,1]$ vanishes, is it true that $\mu$ equals to $0$ on $ [0,1]$?

Tags: measure-theory

I am having difficulties to deal with following problems;

Assume $ \displaystyle\int_{[0,1]} x^n d \mu =0$ for all $n$, 
then is it true that $\mu=0$ on [0,1]?

I think it is definitely true.. but I don't know how to proceed..

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Polynomials are dense in $C([0,1])$, and the Borel measures are dual to $C([0,1])$. (@Jose27 $\delta_0(x \mapsto x^0) = 1$).

Comment: @martini: Of course, I forgot about the constant. Thanks.

Comment: @martini: Borel (signed) measures of bounded variation are dual to $C[0,1]$, could we have a general Borel measure where this fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main interest of teh problem is to show that we can't find a finite *signed* measure satisfying $\int_{[0,1]}t^nd\mu(t)=0$ for all integer $n\geq 0$ (missing $n=0$, as mentioned before, would make the problem wrong with the counter-example $\delta_0$). If we assume $\mu\geq 0$ then the problem is trivial.

Let $\mu=\mu^+-\mu^-$ the Jordan decomposition of $\mu$, where $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ are non-negative measures. We have, by Stone-Weierstrass theorem, that $\int_{[0,1]}f(t)d\mu(t)=0$ for all $f$ continuous on $[0,1]$.

As the characteristic function of a closed set $F$ can be approximated pointwise by continuous functions $f_n$ such that $0\leq f_n\leq 1$, we have by dominated convergence theorem applied to $\mu^+$ and $\mu^-$ that $\mu^+(F)=\mu^-(F)$ for all $F$ closed. This can be extended to all Borel subsets of $[0,1]$, as they generate this $\sigma$-algebra and are stable by (finite) intersections. So $\mu=0$.

Comment: What you trying to say is that above problem indeed becomes challenging if we assume mu need not be a measure but allow it to be a signed measure?

Comment: what if we just assume that mu is complex Borel measure? It does not affect your conclusions as well?

Comment: Complex measure (of bounded variation) are not a problem, as we can write $\mu=\mu_1+i\mu_2$, where $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are signed measures. The main problem is: what if we don't assume $\mu$ to have bounded variation?

Answer (score 0):

You are not saying if you include $n=0$ in your conditions. If you do, then the equation for $n=0$ is $\mu([0,1])=0$.

Assuming you don't, it's not true in the generality you are asking. The problem with using the functions $\{x^n\}$ to define your measure is that they are all $0$ at $0$. So if $\mu$ is the Dirac measure, i.e.
$$
\mu(R)=\begin{cases}1,&\ \text{ if } 0\in R\\0,&\ \text{ if} 0\not\in R\end{cases}
$$
Then $\displaystyle\int_{[0,1]}x^n\,d\mu=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: hmm.. you mean if we include n=0 in the condition, then it becomes trivial? since $\mu [0,1]=0 $ and any other subset $E$ of [0,1] should satisfy $\mu (E)= 0$ by monotonicity?

Comment: @mathlover: yes. If you include $n=0$, then it is well-known that the sequence of those moments determines the measure uniquely, because polynomials are dense in the continuous functions; but if you fail to include $n=0$, you are only considering polynomials which are zero at the origin.